# sample column without duplicates

Tags: r, sampling, random

I'm currently writing a custom function to achieve this, but I was wondering if there was a simple, built-in function in R that would achieve the same goals.

I have data like:

```
stringVariable1     stringVariable2

string1             a
string1             b
string1             d
string2             e
string2             a
string3             b
```

And I want to shuffle the data in stringVariable2, but I don't want duplicates in respect to the different stringVariables in 1.

So this wouldn't be acceptable (as 'b' is duplicated with respect to string1):

```
stringVariable1     stringVariable2

string1             b
string1             b
string1             d
string2             a
string2             e
string3             d
```

But this would:

```
stringVariable1     stringVariable2

string1             b
string1             e
string1             d
string2             a
string2             e
string3             d
```

So essentially I'm trying to randomise the stringVariable2, without replacement with respect to the different stringVariable1's. Is creating a custom function the only way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: depends on the performance... for instance you could shuffle var2, check for duplicates, and reshuffle if needed

Comment: I contemplated that, but the data has over 1 million rows with a lot of duplicated string variables, so the probability of getting at least one duplicate is over 99%

Comment: (and I want to run this about 10000 times)

Answer (score 2):

Are the values of stringVariable2 duplicated in the groups of stringVariable1? If not, a group-wise permutation could be performed with something like (d is the name of the data frame containing the data):

```
d$perm1<-as.vector(unlist(tapply(d$stringVariable2, d$stringVariable1, sample)))
```

This (`tapply()`) applies sampling without replacement (using `sample()`) for stringVariable2 inside every group of stringVariable1. Finally, the resulting list is converted to a vector using `unlist()` and `as.vector()`. The last function just strips off the names of observations inside the vector. The permuted values are then stored ìn the column perm1 of the original data frame.

Comment: Ahh, I've just noticed that this doesn't quite do what I want. For instance, with this method 'e' could never be associated with string1 after the sampling method - and I want the variable 2 to be essentially randomised but that you get no duplicates in each stringvariable1 category. Would you mind having a quick look at it?

Comment: Often the randomization follows some features of the dataset or the experimental setup. I thought that the stringVariable1 was some kind of blocking, but I guess it was not. I can't, at least right now, figure out a fast and a convenient alternative that would generally achieve exactly what you requested. Have you checked the tools available in the permute package (see especially the vignette)? It lets you specify complicated randomization schemes that could fit your needs, also.